# Bigcommerce - Which html file is %%GLOBAL_ViewOrderStatusMsg%%?

Tags: bigcommerce

I want to know how to find html file or settings (%%GLOBAL_ViewOrderStatusMsg%%).

[image: Please see my screen shot that is highlight with yellow.]

Answer (score 0):

There is not a template or file that will allow you to change the value of `%%GLOBAL_ViewOrderStatusMsg%%`. It is something that has been set within the BigCommerce core application and can only be changed by engineers.

You can change the variable to a static string/sentence as a workaround.